# How to get two TreeViews to display side-by-side?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, panel

This seems quite trivial but I can't seem to find out how to place two TreeViews (or any control with a TreeView) so that they sit right next to each other.

Any attempt always results in the TreeView claiming its own line on the displayed page. In other worse, the TreeView always ends up below or above the other control that I want it to be next to.

I've also tried to do this with two panels next to each other and they would simply sit on top of one another. I am sure I am missing something basic.

How do I place any of these controls so they are displayed right next to one another?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code and any css. It looks like the controls are not getting themselves fixed positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u tried

```
<table>
<tr><td>First Tree View<td>
<td>Second Tree Vie</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: How very silly of me. That's it. I completely forgot about using tables. Thank you! As a side question, can you offer any explanation as to why some controls (like Buttons) can be placed side by side without tables, but others (like TreeViews and Panels) can't?

Comment: Other control renders as html control but panel server control renders as an HTML <div> element, so they dosen't render side by side.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you again. +1 for explaining.